# iOS: Could not cast value of type NextViewContrller to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, xcode8

I'm trying to implement navegationController to switch between viewcontrollers programmatically:

[image]

```
@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "next", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "next"{
            let destNVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let next = destNVC.topViewController as! NextViewController
            next.title = "next!"
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'myProject.NextViewController' (0x108de5338) to 'UINavigationController' (0x10aa2d4a8).
```

[image]

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the rightmost VC shown in the screenshot is your `NextViewController`.

Let's see what is `segue.destination` in this situation. It's really easy to find what `segue.destination` refers to. Look at your storyboard, find the segue you want, and find the end of the segue with the arrow. Whatever VC the arrow is pointing to, is `segue.destination`. (the other end of the segue is the `segue.source` btw)

Now that we know this, we know that `segue.destination` in this case must refer to `NextViewController`. Now you should realise that this line should be corrected:

```
let destNVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
```

Well, trying to cast a `NextViewController` to `UINavigationController` will definitely result in an error, won't it?

In fact, you can just cast `segue.destination` to `NextViewController`!

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "next"{
        let next = segue.destination as! NextViewController
        next.title = "next!"
    }
}
```